# Создание Add-in для Office в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access

Поставил пакет разработки расширений для офиса, но в списке шаблонов не могу найти Access, хотя все остальные шаблоны офисных проектов присутствуют(Word, Excel и т д)

Подскажите, для Access нельзя разрабатывать расширения или нужно что-то дополнительно поставить?

Не помешал бы так же, по возможности, банальный пример, например, при открытии Access вылетает какой-нибудь hello world.

---

Нашел какой-то платный [инструментарий](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2010/09/27/office-access-2010-addins/). Однако, неужели нет ничего, что доступного из коробки?

Answer (score 1):

Есть такие инструменты для Access'a http://www.skrol29.com/us/vtools.php
И к ним есть исходные коды http://www.skrol29.com/us/sourcecode.php

Может быть это поможет :}

Погуглил и нашел еще кое-что:

Есть шаблон проекта vsto плагина Access'a для vs2010 gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/VSTO-Access-Template-4dedb360

Обертка, позволяющая создавать плагины для access в том числе netoffice.codeplex.com Там есть примеры!

Нашел еще слегка костыльный вариант создания VSTO плагина для Access'a - создать из шаблона для Word и немного изменить код: blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andreww/2008/02/19/vsto-add-ins-for-access

Answer (score 1):

Официальная позиция Microsoft заключается в том, что создание надстроек (VSTO) для Access НЕ поддерживается. В Visual Studio нет шаблона для создания любого типа надстройки VSTO для Access. Однако, это не значит, что ничего нельзя сделать. Можно попробывать инструменты рекомендованные @AleXander или приглядеться к [Office Access Web App](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/access/access-web-app-add-ins)

Comment: Это кто же такой умный по Microsoft Access чтобы решать что ответ не полезен ? Хоть бы комментарий оставил, а то же как заяц, сделал дело и в кусты